# How to map different trackpad gestures in a per-application basis?

Tags: trackpad, image-editing, gesture

For instance when using Photoshop together with some other editing tool, when I switch between the apps I mistakenly do the gestures to zoom/pan on the wrong application, so I wonder whether there is a way to map different gestures like so:

If working on Photoshop then take a two finder swapping gesture (vertical scroll) as if it where a pinching gesture, otherwise take it as is. Also change the two finger drag gesture while clicking by the two finger drag without clicking.

I know it sounds convoluted but that's the kind of metal burden one has to deal when constantly switching between different editing software.

Comment: Have you tried [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net/)?  I think that's 'the standard' for doing what you're looking for.

Comment: @fbara, I haven't used it yet, thanks for pointing out, I'll give it a try.

Comment: If it works for you, respond back here and let us know.  I'll add it as the answer for you to accept.

Comment: @fbara, unfortunately it doesn’t work for the kind of gestures I’m describing. I guess what I need is a tool to continuously convert one kind of gesture into another while its being performed instead of after it's finished.

Comment: I've read, but don't have experience, about Karabiner which does custom mouse/trackpad events. It can't be set in Sierra yet but if you have an older OS it might work.